# C# - Multilingual string for "Cancel"

Tags: c#, string, button, multilingual

I want to make multilingual buttons, like those of the messagebuttons.
I have a form with a cancel-button, but I want to have a multilingual text.
For example, in German it is named "Abbrechen, in French "Annuler" and in English "Cancel". Like for MessageBoxes, those buttons are also multilingual.
Is it possible to find out the string of the "MessageBox-Cancel-Button" of the current Language of the machine?

Regards

Wonderwhy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN link "Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Is there no easier method? The "Cancel"-String of the system must be saved on the computer, for example, for messageboxbuttons.
I don't want to create a new ressourcefile or multiple forms, I only want the "Cancel"-string of the current language installed on the computer. Isn't this possible?

Comment: You don't create a resource for each form, you create one resource that maps each strings to languages.  For example, your "Cancel" and "Ok" Messages boxes will use the same resource file.  And since you have custom forms with customs labels, having your own resources means everything can be localized, not just whatever the system can localize.

Comment: Thx for the advise.
Now I must find the different "cancel"-strings foreach language :D